# magic1.dll missing, unable to restore

Tags: windows-10, dll

I was uninstalling some programs I don't use on my Windows 10 (can't remember whqt) when suddenly I started getting error dialogs claiming magic1.dll is missing when I use mkvmerge.exe from command line. I have also reinstalled mkvtoolnix just to make sure if this fixes anything. It didn't.

I also tracked down a copy of this file online and registered it (to system32). STILL not working. What can I do to avoid fresh installation of windows? I can't just install a new copy over my old windows (to preserve the settings etc) because apparently I need 7gb extra space on that partition for some reason.

Comment: what is this pip/pip3 command? I don't think I have that. I ran sfc but it found nothing.

Comment: I think I was assuming this was related to a Python package which can usually be reinstalled with the Python install tool called pip that you can usually just go to Windows command line and type in `pip install <package>` to install it. Maybe this is related to that other thing  `mkvtoolnix` but if you haven't already done so, fully uninstall `mkvtoolnix` reboot the machine, and then reinstall `mkvtoolnix` and see if that helps. Otherwise I'm not sure unless it's a Python package or module that needs reinstalled per the pip command or whatever.